# Heroku rake db:seed throws rollback errors, but DB migration and seeding works in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, deployment, migration

I've run several migrations on my rails app and on local, it seems that the only way the DB will seed and render in the view is by executing rails db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed as one command.

When I push to heroku, no errors are raised. But when I run heroku rake db:seed, all of the database post entries raise rollback errors.

I'm mainly confused why Heroku is not registering the relationship between posts. I can upload a picture of my schema below as well.

[Rollback errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPSCC.png)

[relationship does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C049V.png)

Comment: I think the error is saying the posts table does not exist, so you're trying to seed an empty db.

Comment: There is something off with the migration table but heroku logs shows that the posts table was created when I ran heroku rake db:migrate prior to heroku rake db:seed